# Creating a new activity after clicking a link in android?

Tags: android, coding-style

I was trying to style my list items in list view. I thought it would be great if I could create links like HTML links but instead of opening a browser it should open a new intent. I could not find any tutorial with my first search on google so dropping my question here. Please suggest me what to look for.

Regards,
Lalith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to stick with the "standard" look and feel for the system. That is, users expect to be able to tap on a row and it do it's thing (no link looking text).

If you just want the items to *look* like links then underline them and make them blue. If your question is how to launch a new intent after a user taps a "link" take a peek at this [post on anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/tinytutlistactivity_with_startsubactivity-t1889.html).

Comment: I was just playing around with android twitter app. It displays the tweets which can also show links of users. When I click on it it takes me to a new Intent which displays the tweets from that user. Thought I could do something like that easily. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I don't know for sure but you might want to look into http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html